# 3D plotting in scilab

Tags: matlab, scilab

How can I plot 3D figures in scilab? I'm looking for something like [pcshow](https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcshow.html) in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not function like this one in Scilab, so you have to draw figures by yourself using "param3d" function.

Last year I started creating a drawing toolbox for that, unfortunately it is still not completed. However, you could get the idea about how to create some figures as circles, cones, etc. from the source code. You could find it in my [GitHub](https://github.com/dgerod/gfx4scilab/tree/master/drawing/primitives) repository.

Please, consider it is been developed in Scilab 5 and I have still not tested it in Scilab 6.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know what type of figure you want to draw.

As said by [dgerod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1460453/dgerod), looking at `param3d` and `plot3d` is the first thing to do. You can also look for the [`plotlib`](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/plotlib/) ATOMS Package. But as far as i know, there nothing that replicate the Matlab's pcshow function.